# Front Panel Audio Connector

Tags: audio, motherboard, front-panel

I have trouble with connecting the Front Panel Audio Connector. My motherboard is "Asus M4N78 SE" and case is "MODECOM HARRY MIDI 8300". I think audio connectors are well plugged like in manual. In BIOS is selected "HD audio". I don't have any warnings in Device Manager, but when I first time check Device Manager I had a few warnings, after this I had bluesrceen.

My bluescreen minidump files: http://www.filedropper.com/083016-20156-01_1 and http://www.filedropper.com/083016-18812-01

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is missing some details. Please edit your question with details like...If the front panel is disconnected from the motherboard, do you still get the blue screen? Are you running the latest BIOS for the motherboard? Have you verified the pin out of the front panel connector to the pin out of the motherboard?

Comment: Also, are you sure the front panel connector of the case is HD audio capable? I was able to find the manual, but it is not in English.

Comment: @CharlieRB [`Wyposażona została w 2 porty USB 2.0, port HD Audio oraz CD-COVER.`](http://www.modecom.pl/harry_midi_8300_8300b/midi/obudowy/obudowy_i_akcesoria/produkty/) I see HD Audio there :)

Comment: Exactly this sentence mean that the case have 2 ports USB 2.0, port HD Audio and CD-COVER. I need to update to latest BIOS and currently I haven't got any bluescreens. I will reply soon :)

Comment: Ok, so I currently don't have any bluescreens. I updated BIOS to latest version and problem still exist...I plugged pins to AAFP socket like in case manual...Also when i try connect headphones to rear audio panel, effect is same.